# How do I get QSL cards from the Incoming Bureau?

Tags: united-states, qsl-card, arrl

I'm new to QSLing and want to know how to get QSL cards from an incoming bureau in the USA. I have sent outgoing cards recently and want to know how to acquire the replies. Could somebody describe the process?

AI7OW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First go to one of these pages and find the QSL Bureau that serves your area.
https://www.qsl.net/va3rj/qsl_buro2.html
http://www.arrl.org/qsl-service

They will have instructions. In general you will send them stamped self address envelopes large enough to hold a dozen or so QSL cards. As QSL card for you come into the bureau volunteers will sort them and out them into the envelopes you provided. They will them periodically mail them to you.

A few HAMs will send their QSL cards directly to you instead of going through a bureau.

Comment: Thank you very much.